# ¿Existe alguna tecnología que permite crear un efecto mascara con el movil sobre una grafica?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

¿Alguien sabe si con la tecnología de ahora es posible utilizar la camara del móvil por hacer un efecto mascara sobre una ilustración?

Me explico... Pasando el móvil encima de una ilustración en papel, me gustaria que en la camara del móvil me aparece la misma imagen pero en un crop (o un circulo) mas pequeño un fundo de la imagen diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Mirko. Por favor, lee [ask] para aprender a hacer preguntas de calidad. Tu pregunta se basa en opinones ya que es una pregunta abierta a los usuarios sobre distintas tecnologias que puedan hacer eso. L as preguntas han de ser objetivas, dudas concretas y con ejemplos que puedan ser comprobados por cada uno. Mira [Ejemplo minimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides se llama *Realidad Aumentada*. Hay aplicaciones que añaden contenido a la imagen que captura la cámara del móvil, como por ejemplo el Pokemon Go, o el Google Translate que modifica y traduce los textos que captura la cámara del móvil.

Algo similar a lo que buscas lo hace la app Visualizer de Bruguer, que te permite cambiar el color de las paredes de tu casa para ver como quedarían si cambiases su color.

En tu caso se trata de hacer lo mismo pero mezclando parte de la imagen que toma la cámara del móvil con otra que sería el fondo que deseas aplicar. Sencillo dudo que sea, pero por lo menos ya sabes por donde tirar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar! Por IOS se puede hacer? Sin acceder a la camara nativa?

Comment: De IOS la verdad es que no sé mucho, pero en este tutorial pone algo y se ve como muestran puntos del Google maps en la cámara. https://www.raywenderlich.com/146436/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based-2